How to Reproduce a Specific Economic Equilibrium Diagram with TikZ
I'm trying to reproduce a figure from a textbook that depicts international trade equilibria with sanctions using TikZ in LaTeX. Despite my efforts, the resulting figure from my code doesn't closely match the original. I would appreciate any guidance on how to achieve a more accurate reproduction.
Here is the screenshot of the figure I am trying to reproduce:

Here is the LaTeX code I've written so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    % Axis
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[anchor=north] {$M_w, X_T$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=east] {$X_w, M_T$};
    
    % Offer curves
    \draw[thick] (0,0) .. controls (2,1) and (4,2) .. (6,5) node[right] {$t_s$};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (0,0) .. controls (2,0.5) and (4,1) .. (6,3.5) node[right] {$t_0$};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (0,0) .. controls (1,0.5) and (3,1.5) .. (5,4) node[right] {$t'$};
    \draw[thick] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (3,2.5) .. (6,4.5) node[right] {$t_t$};
    
    % Equilibrium points
    \node[draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=above left:$E$] at (4,2.5) {};
    \node[draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=above left:$T$] at (5,3.5) {};
    \node[draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=above left:$W$] at (6,3.5) {};
    \node[draw, fill=black, circle, inner sep=1pt, label=above left:$R$] at (5,4) {};
    
    % Labels
    \node at (6,5) [right] {$t_s$};
    \node at (6,3.5) [right] {$t_0$};
    \node at (5,4) [right] {$t'$};
    \node at (6,4.5) [right] {$t_t$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{International trade equilibria with sanctions.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The issues I'm encountering are:

The shapes of the curves in my diagram do not match those in the original figure.
The placement and labeling of the equilibrium points E,T,W and R are not precise.



I've taken the liberty of making your code snippet minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Please provide some descriptive or background information about the qualitative nature of the various curves. E.g., what are the slopes of the four (half)rays through the origin? What are the functional characteristics of the three bent curves? A separate issue: You mention four [4] equilibrium point labels, but only one of them ("E") would actually appear to represent some kind of equilibrium; the other three labels would, instead, appear to be associated with the three bent curves, no? Please clarify. Incidentally, providing a mention of the source of the screeshot would be a nice touch.

Can you please add a screenshot of your codes result? // Try using to[out=,in=] instead of the controls. Easier to visualize, often more bending than enough.

Can‘t try your code at the moment. You may want to have a look at intersect, when two paths cross each other at least once. // Unfortunately it's not clear whether or not you want to change the original drawing. If so, it's not very clear what you want. E.g. do you want the dots positioned on the same curve?

While the OP is waiting for Tikz-help, here (purely for comparison) is a version done in Metapost, the drawing language available in lualatex with the luamplib pacakge.

To produce a PDF of the above image, you should compile this source with lualatex.  I have added some explanatory comments.  For tutorials and reference guides for MP, follow the link above.
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

  % define the axes and the t* lines
  path xx, yy, tt, ts, tz, ta;
  xx = origin -- 233 right;
  yy = xx rotated 90;

  tt = xx rotated 8;
  ts = xx rotated 82;

  % these two are a bit longer
  tz = xx scaled 1.14 rotated 45;   
  ta = xx scaled 1.14 rotated 40;

  % define point E, about 2/3 of the way along t0;
  pair E;
  E = point .678 of tz;

  % define the curves
  path T, W, R;
  W = origin {dir 80} .. E .. 260 dir 34 {dir 8}; 

  % second one is just a reflection of the first
  T = W reflectedabout(origin, E);

  % third one is another reflection, but also trimmed to look neat
  R = T reflectedabout(origin, (subpath(1/4, 1) of ta intersectionpoint T))
        cutafter yy shifted (xpart point 2 of W, 0);

  % now draw and label the t* lines, with a fancy loop
  forsuffixes $=tt, ta, ts, tz:
    draw $ dashed withdots scaled 1/4;
    string a; picture t;
    a = substring (1,2) of str $;
    t = thelabel("$t" & if a = "a": "^*" elseif a = "z": "_0" else: "_" & a fi & "$", point 1 of $);
    unfill bbox t; draw t;
  endfor

  % draw the curves on top, without using a fancy loop
  draw W withcolor 2/3 blue; label.rt ("$W$", point 2 of W);
  draw T withcolor 2/3 blue; label.top("$T$", point 2 of T);
  draw R withcolor 2/3 blue; label.rt ("$R$", point 2 of R);

  % label E
  dotlabel.ulft("$E$", E);

  % draw and label the axes
  drawarrow xx; label.rt ("$M_W$, $X_T$", point 1 of xx);
  drawarrow yy; label.top("$X_W$, $M_T$", point 1 of yy);
  label.llft("$0$", origin);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}

